# Looping through a map data structure in Haskell

Tags: loops, haskell, dictionary

I have a map data structure that has the following structure:-
"What is the capital of UK"-> "London"
"What is the capital of France"-> "Paris"
I want to loop through this map displaying the question: "What is the capital of UK", asking for user input. If the user answers "London" I print correct, otherwise, I print the correct answer "London". This is easy in an imperative language like C# but I haven't figured how to do it in Haskell.

Comment: Why do you use a map for this? A map is for _looking up_ values according to keys. If you just want to store / process _values and also keys_, why not just use a list of tuples? Looping over such a list is [trivial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:forM_). (If a map is all you've given, then just convert it to a tuple-list...)

Comment: Why is that a `Map String String` instead of just a `[(String, String) ]`?

Comment: Check out http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output

Comment: one simple seed code is `sequence_ [print (k,v) | (k,v) <- toList theMap]`.

Comment: Convert the map to a list and then use a "for loop": `forM_ (Map.toList m) $ \(k,v) -> do ...` from `Data.Foldable`

Comment: `Data.Map.traverseWithKey` can be useful as well.

Comment: Why is everyone assuming "map" means `Data.Map.Map`?

Comment: @ReidBarton Because the word `map` is used to refer to a type of structure.  No, it is not a reasonable assumption given that the asker is a self-professed Haskell beginner.

Answer (score 9):

The issue with using `Map` in this manner is a lot of the traversals over `Map` values assume you don't care about the key and only care about the contained value.  There are traversals inside `Data.Map` that suffice, and @danidiaz has pointed on out, but it's totally reasonable to call `toList` since that list will be generated lazily, not forced into memory all at once.  Given a list of tuples (key, value) you can traverse that using `for` or `mapM` or `fmap` or .... basically any of the constructs you love so long as you can use an IO monad.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}
import Data.Foldable (for_)
import Data.Map (Map,toList)

m :: Map String String
m = [("a","1"),("b","2")]

main =
  for_ (toList m) $ \(q,a) ->
    do putStrLn q
       x <- getLine
       putStrLn (if x == a
                    then "Yes"
                    else "No: " ++ a)
```

EDIT: I feel compelled to add what most people would call more idiomatic Haskell using `mapM_`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ ask (toList m)

ask :: (String,String) -> IO ()
ask (q,a) = do putStrLn q
               x <- getLine
               putStrLn (if x == a then "Yes" else "No: " ++ a)
```

Comment: Haskell is not accepting m::Map String String as valid, I have tried m :: ([Char],[Char]) but that does not work either.

Comment: @user3480820 I suggest you post this issue as a separate question.  I don't know what code you are using, what compilation command you ran, or what "not accepting" really means here.  When you ask the next question please be sure to include the exact code you are using and the compiler error.  Notice the first code block in my answer is complete and should work fine if you copy and paste it into a `foo.hs` file and interpret or compile it with a reasonably recent version of `ghc`.

Answer (score 2):

`lens`'s [`ifor_` combinator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#v:ifor_) allows you to write @ThomasM.DuBuisson's code without going via `toList`. The traversal function gets access to the index at each iteration.

```
main = ifor_ m $ \(q, a) -> do
    putStrLn q
    x <- getLine
    putStrLn (if x == a then "Yes" else "No: " ++ a)
```