# Looping over a map in haskell

Tags: loops, haskell, dictionary

```
import Data.Foldable (for_)
import Data.Map (Map,toList)

m :: Map String String
m = [("a","1"),("b","2")]

main =
  for_ (toList m) $ \(q,a) ->
    do putStrLn q
       x <- getLine
       putStrLn (if x == a
                    then "Yes"
                    else "No: " ++ a)
```

I get the error:-

```
foo.hs:5:5: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Map String String'
                  with actual type `[([Char], [Char])]'
    * In the expression: [("a", "1"), ("b", "2")]
      In an equation for `m': m = [("a", "1"), ("b", "2")]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Thanks for your help. I was interested in the for_i solution , but I cannot load Control.Lens

Comment: To those who voted to close: Take note I suggested the asker make a separate question based on the fact that the first one was really an almost off-topic "I've no idea where to start" where as this is a "I've a syntax or type error and can not understand it" style issue.  In my eyes they are sufficiently different.

Comment: Also, to load `Control.Lens` you'll first need to install the `lens` package likely by `cabal install lens` or perhaps `stack install lens`.  After that you should be able to write `import Control.Lens` at the top of the file to get access to the mentioned `ifor_` function.  Notice we can decompose `ifor_` into  "indexed (the 'i') for loop (the 'for') that ignores the result of each iteration (the '_')".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have taken the code from [this answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42566616/791604), but omitted the first line:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}
```

Don't omit the first line.

Answer (score 2):

`Map String String` is not just an alias for lists of tuples; it is a distinct data type, and so your assignment does not type-check. You need to use the function `Data.Map.fromList` to convert your list to a proper `Map k v` value.

```
m = Data.Map.fromList [("a","1"),("b","2")]
```

Comment: Unifying this answer with Daniel's.  A `Map` is a distinct type from a `List`.  The syntax `[val1, val2]` is traditionally a list but the language extension `OverloadedLists` makes the syntax include an implicit `fromList` call, making the fully de-sugared translation `[val1,val2] ~> fromList (val1 : val2 : [])`.

Comment: This now works. I can't get the for_i to work, after downloading lens, but I'm not too worried about this. Thank you again.